# What's the best way to seperate the first line of a string from the rest in JS?

Tags: javascript, string

In Python, there was good old `firstline, rest = text.split("\n", 1)`. After some painful discovery, I realized that JavaScript gives a different meaning to the *limit* property, and returns that many "splits" (1 means it returns only the first line, 2 returns only the first two lines, and so forth).

What's the best way to get what I wanted? Do I have to make do with `slice` and `indexOf`?

Comment: Oddly enough, the splice method doesn't even make the code longer, at all...

Comment: not sure why I thought this was a question on Ruby, but just in case... `first, rest = text.split ?\n, 2`

Comment: I'm getting into Ruby dev. At least you guys have clean object unpacking. ;-;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way:

```
function getFirstLine(text) {
    var index = text.indexOf("\n");
    if (index === -1) index = undefined;
    return text.substring(0, index);
}
```

Then:

```
// "Some string goes here"
console.log(getFirstLine("Some string goes here\nSome more string\nAnd more\n\nMore"));
// "asdfasdfasdf"
console.log(getFirstLine("asdfasdfasdf"));
```

**Edit:**

```
function newSplit(text, lineSplit) {
    if (lineSplit <= 0) return null;

    var index = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < lineSplit; i++) {
        index = text.indexOf("\n", index) + 1;
        if (index === 0) return null;
    }

    return { 0: text.substring(0, index - 1), 1: text.substring(index) }
}
```

Output:

```
newSplit("someline\nasdfasdf\ntest", 1);
    > Object {0: "someline", 1: "asdfasdf↵test"}
newSplit("someline\nasdfasdf\ntest", 2);
    > Object {0: "someline↵asdfasdf", 1: "test"}
newSplit("someline\nasdfasdf\ntest", 0);
    > null
newSplit("someline\nasdfasdf\ntest", 3);
    > null
```

Comment: The idea was to get both the first line and everything else., but thank you.

Comment: @Glycan Simply change the last line to `return { "firstline":text.substring(0, index), "rest":text.substring(index) }` and access the `firstline` and `rest` properties of the result.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll cook something up.

Comment: I only need to use this once, so it's kind of irrelevant to have it as a function.

Comment: @Glycan then take it out of the function. Check if the `newSplit` works like you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to remove the first item from an array.

```
var lines = text.split("\n");   // split all lines into array
var firstline = lines.shift();   // read and remove first line
var rest = lines.join("\n");     // re-join the remaining lines
```

This is perhaps idomatically closest to what you do in Python, but it's hardly the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, using a regex with `String.match` and `Array.slice`

Javascript

```
var text = "Simple Simon met a Pieman,\ngoing to a fair.\nSaid simple Simon to the Pieman,\n\n\"Let me taste your ware.\"";

console.log((text.match(/^([\s\S]*?)\n([\s\S]*)$/) || []).slice(1, 3));
```

Output

```
["Simple Simon met a Pieman,", "going to a fair.↵Said simple Simon to the Pieman,↵↵"Let me taste your ware.""]
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/axjK5/)

Comment: this will be very inefficient on large text blobs

Answer (score 0):

The RegExp.exec() method will do the trick:

```
//some multiline text
var text='line1\nline2'
//exec puts the first line in an array
var firstline=/.*/.exec(text)[0]
```

REPL Output:

```
>>> firstline
line1
```

When the regex is saved as an object with global and multiline flags, exec can be used to step through each line in a loop, manually shown here in the jsc REPL:

```
>>> var reg = /^.*/gm
>>> var text='line1\nline2'
>>> reg.exec(text)
line1
>>> reg.exec(text)
line2
>>> reg.exec(text)
null
```